# Unity freezes because of script, but i don't know whats wrong with said script

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

Bear with me, I'm pretty new to unity.
As the title suggests, the game engine freezes when this script is attached to the main camera.

```
public class leftright : MonoBehaviour {
    public float boundaries = 3f;

    void Update () {
        while (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < boundaries && Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > -boundaries) {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this script makes an infinite loop, and I can't detect any problem with it.

the log text is [here,](https://pastebin.com/Yp0hTzUg) and the project is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/wbbyqxup41qjxh8/Unity_test.zip/file)

Comment: Note about the [tag:visual-studio] tag: if you read the description, it says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
While(true) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The conditional you're using in your `while` statement cannot (and will not) ever change from `true` to `false` based on the contents of the loop, therefor it will run forever.

`Update()` is *already* a loop, treat it like one.

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < boundaries && Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > -boundaries) {
        this.transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);
    }
}
```